# HCl labeled 31.45% concentration (20° Baume)

Tags: concentration, home-experiment

Just bought a standard concentration of HCl solution. The 31.45% is weight-by-weight & not weight-by-volume, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *this* is mass concentration, reporting concentration by weight.

E.g., Oxy/OxyChem's documentation *Hydrochloric Acid Handbook* ([link to pdf file)](https://www.oxy.com/globalassets/documents/chemicals/products/chlor-alkali/hydrochloric_acid_handbook.pdf), edition 08/2018 explicitly states how the two relate to each other on page 6 with:

> «OxyChem produces and markets Technical Grade hydrochloric acid in two concentrations: 22° Baumé (35.21% HCl by wt.) and 20° Baumé (31.45% HCl by
> wt.). Other dilute concentrations of hydrochloric acid may be available upon request.»